# Full text index issue

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am creating a full text search index like this:

```
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX ON [dbo].[vwBusinessSearch] ([Address] LANGUAGE 1033,[City] LANGUAGE 1033,[State] LANGUAGE 1033,[Registration No] LANGUAGE 1033,[Phone] LANGUAGE 1033,[Contact Phone] LANGUAGE 1033,[Contact Fax] LANGUAGE 1033,[Fax] LANGUAGE 1033,[Business Name] LANGUAGE 1033) KEY INDEX [IX_Registry_ID_Business] ON [ft_cat_CreditRegistry_Nigeria] WITH CHANGE_TRACKING OFF
GO

ALTER FULLTEXT INDEX ON [dbo].[vwBusinessSearch] ENABLE

GO
```

but getting following error:

```
SQL03006: Full-text Index contains an unresolved reference to an object. Either the object does not exist or the reference is ambiguous because it could refer to any of the following objects:
```

If I try to create an index like this:

```
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Registry_ID_Business] ON [dbo].[vwBusinessSearch] ([Registry ID]) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

I get following:

```
SQL04127: The table or view ([dbo].[vwBusinessSearch]) has more than one clustered index.
```

Please suggest solution to this.

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that only columns of type char, varchar, nchar, nvarchar, text, ntext, image, xml, varbinary  or varbinary(max) are to be included in yout full-text index? It seems like [Registration No] might not be one of the above?!